# Sfc returned a hash mismatch for cmd.exe, how do I fix this

Tags: windows, command-line, 64-bit, sfc

My mom has screen time restrictions on my computer (I'm a Junior) and I, as any normal kid would do, found out how to get into it, but the way I did it was by deleting all files in System32 that began with "Wpc" (Windows Parental Controls). Unrelated, for some reason WpcRefreshTask just disables the windows key so I didn't delete that one. The issue is that I'm not good with computers, so I just did the vanilla bootable usb, ren cmd utilman, and did it from there. After realizing that windows thought my cmd was a corrupted file and just sort of wiped it I guess?
I sfc'd and it restored all of the files including cmd. For various reasons I did it a second time, and now it gives me the error:

```
2023-04-11 23:06:03, Info                  CSI    0000020e Hashes for file member [l:7]'cmd.exe' do not match.
 Expected: {l:32 ml:33 b:b99d61d874728edc0918ca0eb10eab93d381e7367e377406e65963366c874450}.
 Actual: {l:32 b:c5ebf3e44d223df5119af777d33640863871111bbe957c6a9ac161d07e9dc853}.
2023-04-11 23:06:03, Info                  CSI    0000020f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:7]'cmd.exe' of Microsoft-Windows-CommandPrompt, version 10.0.19041.746, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2023-04-11 23:06:03, Info                  CSI    00000210 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:158]'Microsoft-Windows-Client-Desktop-Required-Package0511~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.19041.2728.0ADA595A6E609C41B28DC326310A896371B2A3AEEDF85A2A82D547F15ED35CD3'
2023-04-11 23:06:03, Info                  CSI    00000211 Hashes for file member [l:7]'cmd.exe' do not match.
 Expected: {l:32 ml:33 b:b99d61d874728edc0918ca0eb10eab93d381e7367e377406e65963366c874450}.
 Actual: {l:32 b:c5ebf3e44d223df5119af777d33640863871111bbe957c6a9ac161d07e9dc853}.
2023-04-11 23:06:03, Info                  CSI    00000212 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\\cmd.exe; source file in store is also corrupted
```

(Sorry for the story, figured it might be helpful to know what I've done in the past two days for reference.)

Also side note I did give the data from location 1 to location 2, because I'm stupid

`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\PersistentHandler`
**>**
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\PersistentHandler`

Again, I'm not the best with computers, and all of my shortcuts turned into urls, so I made a (very smart) decision which was that :\ (It didn't fix it)

Comment: You have to re-install windows. What-ever other advice you get & Execute , it may make your system even more corrupt !